# YII2 Count and Group by

Tags: postgresql, gridview, yii2

I have some three tables

```
Roles => role_id, role_name, store_id

Stores => store_id, store_name

UserRoles => id, user_id, role_id
```

I need to find for each store and role how many users have permission

> Sql(Postgre) is

```
SELECT    Count(*), 
          store_name 
FROM      "roles" 
LEFT JOIN "user_roles" 
ON        "roles"."role_id" = "user_roles"."role_id" 
LEFT JOIN "locations" 
ON        "roles"."rol_loc_id" = "stores"."loc_id" 
GROUP BY  (roles.rol_id,store_id) 
order BY  roles.rol_id
```

Now In Yii I have smth like this

```
$query = Roles::find()
             ->select('*')
             ->joinWith("userRoles")
             ->joinWith('store');
```

When I add

```
         ->groupBy(['roles.role_id','store_id'])
```

OR

```
         count() OR ->select(["count(*) as countUserForEachStore])
```

It  not works , because sql query is look likes this

```
          SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT '.....
```

So I try to use (new \yii\db\Query()) , but in that case I have problem with ActiveDataProvider , because the grid sort, and pagination not work succefully.

Need an advice, how you solve problems like this?

Comment: I think use [Yii2 ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider)

Comment: thanks, I will test it, hope it will work with sort and search...

Comment: The Raw SQL that you have provided above does it work correctly? or shows the desired results? and you wan to convert it using ActiveRecord?

Comment: yes sql work correctly I want to write query that I can set  in ActiveRecord , but when I write it in yii i got different result, because it converts select count(*) from ( count
(*) ...code...  I don't have errors, I just get another result ...I need to count and group by two fields using yii2 and need to know is it possible ?